# Fiddler Error Connecting to HTTPS Applications !SecureClientPipeDirect failed

Tags: fiddler

Fiddler Error Connecting to HTTPS Applications

Fiddler Log:
!SecureClientPipeDirect failed: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. on pipe to (CN=services.bigpond.com, O=DO_NOT_TRUST_BC, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com)

I have followed other posts but no answers

Answer (score 6):

The typical explanation for this message, as documented in many places, is that the client application has not been configured to trust Fiddler's root certificate. As such, the client closes the connection to Fiddler when it sees the untrusted certificate.

http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/TrustFiddlerRootCert

Comment: We're facing the same error message. Works fine if https content is accessed via browser running as same user account. However website running as ApplicationPoolIdentity casues error "!SecureClientPipeDirect failed: System.IO.IOException Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. on pipe to (CN=xxxxxx, O=DO_NOT_TRUST_BC, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com)" 

Do you have any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: @flalar By default, Fiddler's root certificate is trusted in the *User*'s Trusted Certificates store. If you want other user accounts (e.g. ApplicationPoolIdentity) to trust it, you need to move to the *Machine's* Trusted Certificates store.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! **Much appreciated**. Tried to achieve this by running *CertMgr /add %PathTo%FiddlerRoot.cer /s /r localMachine root* but this did unfortunately not resolve the issue at hand. Further tried to view the certificate store for the local machine with the mmc snap-in and found the FiddlerRoot certificate was present in the "Personal" store for the local computer. Am I looking the wrong place?

Comment: From the Fiddler Book: http://www.ericlawrence.com/eric/images/ul/3-4-15-manualtrust.png.png

Answer (score -1):

In Kestrel I'm using an SSL cert.

I 'downgraded' the TLS protocol in order to get this to work.

This is not something you'd do in production - but in production you shouldn't be using kestrel. I'm not saying this is the best overall config, but this is mainly to show the `SslProtocols` option.

```
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000);  // http:localhost:5000
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 44300, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        // https://dotnetthoughts.net/enable-http2-on-kestrel/
                        //listenOptions.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http2;

                        listenOptions.UseHttps(@"S:\WORK\SSL\example.com.pfx", "cert-password", httpsOptions => 
                        {
                            httpsOptions.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls;                                
                        });
                    });
                })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: If you know better please comment :-)